# PHP - What is # for in php used in the context... $form['title'] = array( '#type' => 'textfield')

Tags: php, drupal

It's been a while and I can't find it in PHP manuals. Why is the # used with the key => value

Comment: Could it be referring to an ID? You haven't given enough details for us to be helpful.

Comment: It has no special meaning to PHP.  It's just like `'Xtype' => 'textfield'`.  Maybe it has meaning to the app or person that wrote it.

Comment: When outside of quotes, `#` is a symbol used to comment everything afterwards on that line (just like `//`). But inside quotes, it's just part of that string and has no significant meaning.

Comment: If you find Artreaktor's answer helpful, [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 5):

It's a Drupal renderable arrays convention. Keys containing # symbol are predefined properties (in respective theme function). It means you need to look at the API in order to set such properties correctly.

See [Drupal form API #type](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#type) description.

More about [Drupal renderable arrays](https://www.drupal.org/node/930760).